# ibm cloud object storage upload from CD pipeline - access denied

Tags: continuous-deployment, ibm-cloud-storage

I am trying to automate my deployment to my public COS bucket using the IBM CI/CD pipeline - I do a curl PUT with the payload data and the authorization token.

I can upload using the same script on my local terminal window fine to my COS bucket.

When I do it via the CI/CD pipeline, I get this error:
* upload completely sent off: 22 out of 22 bytes

> `AccessDenied`Access
>   Denied/mbp-ui-subscription/widget-bundle403<
>   HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

I have verified that i am generating the token correctly, is CI/CD pipeline or COS blocking me somehow?

Answer (score 1):

turns out i was not parsing the iam token properly and passing it because it also contains a uaa token

Comment: Is there a place in the docs where it would be helpful to call this out more clearly?